# Deduce the value for a distribution function without using calculus

Tags: probability

> The random variable X has the probability function shown
>
> [image: Probability function]
>
> Deduce the value for k without using calculus.

So, I've gotten as far as P(X=0), P(X=3)=P(X=-3), P(X=2)=P(X=-2) etc..

My intuition also is that the cumulative distribution function must also add to 1. However not sure how this helps find k if I can't take the derivative to find the distribution function.

Should I be using the sum of natural number series to solve this? I little stumped and could use some guidance.

Comment: Tip: This is a continuous distribution.  $\mathsf P(X=0)=0=\mathsf P(X-3)=\ldots$ and so forth for *all* the other points.  Rather, you need to deal with probability densities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability *density* function is clearly: $f_X(x) = k\,\lvert x\rvert\,\mathbf 1_{x\in[-3;3]}$.

It is in the form of two right triangles.   Being a probability *density* function, the combined area of these triangles must equal *something*.   This will give you $k$ without need for integration.

Comment: Very simple, thankyou!